# How do you connect the iMac Minecraft java edition to Minecraft pocket edition?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do you connect Minecraft java edition (iMac) to Minecraft PE (pocket edition) to play a world together?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the Java Edition currently is not compatible with Minecraft PE, so it is impossible to connect the two.